# Jquery .get call not returning anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I've been at this for hours trying to figure out why this will not work. I am trying to read data from my mysql database using php and jquery. In my php file it loops through a table and should echo the results of that table. I am using the jquery .get method to try and retrieve it but i get a 404 error file not found. The 404 error goes away and everything works fine if i change my php file to something simple like:

```
<?php echo 'Hello'; ?>
```

I believe the problem is in my php file because when i create a new file with just echoing a string and nothing else it returns everything fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.get("php/listtasks.php", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
  })
});
```

My php file where i think there is a problem contains:

```
<?php // sqltest.php
require_once 'session.php';
require_once 'login.php';

$conn = new mysqli($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_database);  

if($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);



$query  = "SELECT * FROM list";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . $conn->error);

$rows = $result->num_rows;

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$result->data_seek($j);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);


echo $row[2];



}


$result->close();
$conn->close();


?>
```

Comment: Add an error handler

Comment: Enable error reporting for php, and what does the page/logs say when you directly view the page (not using Ajax)?

Comment: if you remove the first 2 requires does it work?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII trying to set up the error handling now but anytime I just go directly to the php page it sends me to a 404 error trying to redirect to an index.html that doesn't exit.

Comment: Sounds like your login.php is redirecting you.

Comment: Thanks jeff and arthur..turns out my sessions required was messing me up big time, i removed it and now it works..What a waste of 3 hours only to have such an easy fix...sigh

Comment: @nj51 Thats the wonder of programming